# Появилось двойное нажатие на кнопку навигации и т.д

Tags: javascript

Всем драсте... значит работаю на сайтике такой месяц... написал тонну кода и теперь кнопка выпадающего окна работает через 2-е нажатие первый раз, а потом по 1-му...
также кнопка Копировать начала действовать только по двойному нажатию...
Просмотрел код на ошибки, но пользы 0. Хелп может кто сталкивался?

Comment: P.S. Также это происходит на разный страницах. Например в профиле только кнопка копирование ссылки по двойному клику...

Comment: 1000 и 1 причина.